# Processingjs not showing up in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, html, processing, firefox3.6

I'm attempting to develop a new website using the Processsingjs library.  It works fine in Chrome, but the canvas is showing up blank in Firefox.

I can view processingjs.org just fine through the same install of firefox, just not my website.

The code is bare bones:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<script src="includes\processing-0.9.7.js"></script>
<canvas datasrc="test.pjs" width="700" height="500">text</canvas>


// test.pjs

void setup() {
    size(700, 500);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
}
```

It's worth noting that "text" doesn't show up in Firefox.  Can anyone me to troubleshoot?  I can't really think of a simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"includes/processing-0.9.7.js" would be more standard than "includes\processing-0.9.7.js" (ie forward-slash, not back-slash). You need to use a URL, not a Windows path.

Comment: This was the correct solution.  Thank you.  Apparently Chrome was just interpreting my mistake.